# Implementation of Entity Framework in Clean Architecture

Tags: c#, entity-framework-core, .net-5, clean-architecture

I am working on Clean Architecture and Entity Framework but confuse why we need to put Entity (database/ Table property Class) in Core project and DbSet--> DbContext in Infrastructure?? for me domain only concern with business entity which may not same as database entities/ Data Model and most important we are creating dependencies of data layer in Core and what happened when we table column change in database! is that means we change property in Core Project?

Comment: DbSet is not your Domain, it is a detail of implementation. It should be on the edge of your system. What if you need to remove Entity Framework and use, for example, Dapper? In that case, you have to change your domain (core). But you just wanted to change some framework

Comment: @Toxic Have you heard about the [repository pattern](https://www.programmingwithwolfgang.com/repository-pattern-net-core/)?

Comment: Also please see https://github.com/jasontaylordev/CleanArchitecture, https://github.com/ardalis/CleanArchitecture, https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Zygw4UAxCdg&list=PLK0IGvFJlKDzCUVfICHf7w_AY-pW5XP5M&index=2&t=8s

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The reasoning behind this is that Entity Framework models *in theory* should be representative of your Business/Domain Model, and agnostic to your database storage strategy.

> what happened when we table column change in database

Think of the Reason For Change behind most table column changes.

- If you simply find that you have to rename that column to keep your database admins happy, you should be able to change the *mapping* (which resides in your Infrastructure project), and leave your Entity class intact.
- If you're adding a new property, most likely that's because of a fundamental Domain Model change: you're adding some features that require that new property to be there on your Entity. This change will likely impact your core logic, your UI, and other parts of your code, so it makes sense for that change to **start** in the Core project and then require changes in the Infrastructure project to ensure that column is added to the database.

That said, in practice, there's a chance your Domain Model will end up reflecting your database storage strategy to some extent anyway. You'll invariably make design choices around how you store and retrieve data, which properties you'll expect to be populated, etc., based on the knowledge that you're working with an ORM like Entity Framework. If you decided to fundamentally change your data storage strategy (using a Document Store, e.g.) there's still a good chance your core logic would end up changing as a result. Nothing's perfect.

But if you adopt a mental model where your entities represent your Domain Model and the DbContext is merely an implementation detail related to how you store that model, you'll probably make it easier to do things like switching from a SQL Server instance to Azure SQL DB or some other compatible database provider, without having to shuffle core code around.

Comment: that is very good answer and helpful, can I say for example, there is Customer table with 10 columns in database and I have defined as Entity Model in Infrastructure, but in CORE/ domain project I have DataView of Customer class 'CustomerDataView' with 5 properties that satisfies only need for a specific process and so on. Is this approach will be appropriate for Clean Architecture?

Comment: @Toxic: The idea would be that you have the Customer class (with 10 properties) defined in Core, but the fact that it maps to a Customer table with specific named columns is managed with the DbContext in the Infrastructure project. You could also create other useful model classes in Core, like the `CustomerDataView` you mention, especially if they have properties (like aggregates) that would be inefficient to calculate based on the data you'd find on the Customer class. Repository interfaces (defined in Core) could interact with these models. Their implementations interact with DbContext.